# Sub-classing the argparse Argument Parser

Tags: python, derived-class, argparse

I am trying to write a parser class derived from the Python argparse ArgumentParser class. The outlines of the following code work fine on the command line but generate an error I am struggling to understand in the context of my module.

The code (stripped down a little to remove the unimportant stuff) is as follows:

```
class SansParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
"""Argument parser for preparing a SansModel fit or calculation

"""

def __init__(self):
    """Initialisation method for the parser class"""

    argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__(self)


    # Subparsers for the two commands 'calc' and 'fit'
    self.subparsers = self.add_subparsers()
    self.fit_parser = self.subparsers.add_parser('fit', help="Fit a dataset")
    self.fit_parser.add_argument('-d', '-data', '-dataset', type = str,
                                 dest = 'dataset',
                                 help = "The dataset to fit in SasXML format")
    self.fit_parser.set_defaults(func=fit)
    self.calc_parser = self.subparsers.add_parser('calc', prog='test')
    self.calc_parser.set_defaults(func=calculate)
```

I can run the equivalent of this as a script and its fine. If I run it from either shell or import into python command line and try to instantiate the class I get:

```
$ python sansmodel.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "sansmodel.py", line 57, in <module>
      parser = SansParser()
    File "sansmodel.py", line 41, in __init__
      self.fit_parser = self.subparsers.add_parser('fit', help="Fit a dataset")
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py",
    line 1064, in add_parser
      parser = self._parser_class(**kwargs)
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prog'
```

As far as I can tell the code in argparse itself at line 1064 explicitly creates the 'prog' keyword and this is the expected behaviour so I'm confused as to where it is unexpected. I'm guessing I've got something backwards with the scope somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you're overwritting some `argparse.ArgumentParser` behaviour, I recommend to create a parser object and add the arguments and the subparsers to that object.

That said, the problem is that when adding a new parser the `__init__` method, that has been overwritten by the `SansParser` implementation, doesn't accept the same arguments as the original `ArgumentParser`.

A workaround to the problem should be this one:

```
self.subparsers._parser_class = argparse.ArgumentParser
```

This way, when `add_parser` is called, instead of creating a new `SansParser` (that would fail because of infinite recursion), a new `ArgumentParser` will be created.

Comment: Yes that works. I was pretty sure I was just thinking about the problem wrong. Looking at it now it seems to me that it makes more sense to build an app class which has a parser as an object because as you say, I don't need to overwrite any of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jcollado's suggestion to simply add arguments to an `ArgumentParser` object, rather than subclass.

However, if you do subclass, I would recommend you change the signature of your `__init__` method rather than change the value of `self.subparsers._parser_class`.

```
class SansParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
"""Argument parser for preparing a SansModel fit or calculation

"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialisation method for the parser class"""
        if 'my_keyword' in kwargs:
            # Do what needs to be done with kwargs['my_keyword']
            del kwargs['my_keyword'] # Since ArgumentParser won't recognize it

        argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This way, your subclass can work the same way as `ArgumentParser`, except for where you override its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error this afternoon, and found your question when looking for some solution.

If you have read the ArgumentParser's `__init__()`, you could see that it accepts a series of arguments, including right the 'prog':

```
class ArgumentParser(_AttributeHolder, _ActionsContainer):
"""SOME DOC STRING..."""

    def __init__(self,
             prog=None,
             usage=None,
             description=None,
             epilog=None,
             parents=[],
             formatter_class=HelpFormatter,
             prefix_chars='-',
             fromfile_prefix_chars=None,
             argument_default=None,
             conflict_handler='error',
             add_help=True,
             allow_abbrev=True):
        ...... # SOME IMPLEMENTATION
```

I think the fact is: the custom parser class overridden the `__init__()` method, and accepts no argument. But other methods are not modified. This made the methods' behaviors conflict. When creating sub parser, add_parser() calls the parser's `__init__()` with arguments including 'prog'. To ArgumentParser, it's ok, but to the custom parser with overridden `__init__()`, obviously it will fail.

Of course @jcollado's suggestion works fine, but seems it also cancels the customization of sub parser's behavior.

My solution to this problem, a little ugly but also works well. When overriding the `__init__()` of ArgumentParser, just keep every argument and its default value. Like this:

```
class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(
        self,
        prog=None,
        usage=None,
        description=None,
        epilog=None,
        parents=[],
        formatter_class=argparse.HelpFormatter,
        prefix_chars='-',
        fromfile_prefix_chars=None,
        argument_default=None,
        conflict_handler='error',
        add_help=True,
        allow_abbrev=True
        # and your custom arguments here
        ):

        super(MyParser, self).__init__(prog=prog, usage=usage, description=description, epilog=epilog,
                                   parents=parents, formatter_class=formatter_class,
                                   prefix_chars=prefix_chars, fromfile_prefix_chars=fromfile_prefix_chars,
                                   argument_default=argument_default, conflict_handler=conflict_handler,
                                   add_help=add_help, allow_abbrev=allow_abbrev
                                   )
        # and your custom actions here
```