# Make my python command line program interactive with argparse

Tags: python, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

i'm trying to make my python program interactive in command line, user should be able to do stuff like :

```
python myprogram.py --create
```

then

```
python myprogram.py --send
```

The problem in this when is that the program stop and restart each time so i lose my variable and object that i created with the first command.

I'm using argparse on this way:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c','--create' ,help='',action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-s','--send',help='',action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.create:
    create()
elif args.send :
    send()
```

I don't want to stop the program between the command, how to do this ?

example : https://coderwall.com/p/w78iva

Comment: I think what you want is a loop that prints a menu of possible actions, one of them being "quit".

Comment: Argparse has a function to do this. What I need is interact with my program without quit

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple interactive script.  I use `argparse` to parse the input lines, but otherwise it is not essential to the action.  Still it can be an handy way of adding options to your 'create' command.  For example, `ipython` uses `argparse` to handle its `%magic` commands:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', description='description')
parser.add_argument('cmd', choices=['create','delete','help','quit'])

while True:
    astr = raw_input('$: ')
    # print astr
    try:
        args = parser.parse_args(astr.split())
    except SystemExit:
        # trap argparse error message
        print 'error'
        continue
    if args.cmd in ['create', 'delete']:
        print 'doing', args.cmd
    elif args.cmd == 'help':
        parser.print_help()
    else:
        print 'done'
        break
```

This could be stripped down to the `while` loop, the `raw_input` line, and your own evaluation of the `astr` variable.

The keys to using `argparse` here are:

- `parse_args` can take a  list of strings (the result of `split()`) instead of using the default `sys.argv[1:]`.
- if `parse_args` sees a problem (or '-h') it prints a message and tries to 'exit'.  If you want to continue, you need to trap that error, hence the `try` block.
- the output of `parse_args` is a simple namespace object.  You access the arguments as attributes.
- you could easily substitute your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

The diffrence in `cmd` and `argparse` is that `cmd` is a `"line-oriented command interpreter"` while `argparse` is a `parser for sys.argv`.

Your example parses `sys.argv` that you pass while running your program and then if it gets the value you start a function and then quits.

`argparse` will only parse the `sys.argv` while running the program.

You could add some code to be able to work with the `args` you pass like a function or class or make in program menu that you could operate with `raw_input`.
Example:

```
class Main():
  def __init__(self, create=None, send=None):
   if create:
     self.create(create)
   elif send:
     self.send(send)

    option = raw_input('What do you want to do now?')
    print option

  def create(self, val):
    print val

  def send(self, val):
    print val


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('-c','--create' ,help='',action='store_true')
  parser.add_argument('-s','--send',help='',action='store_true')
  args = parser.parse_args()

  Main(args.create, args.send)
```

Other then that [Python argparse and controlling/overriding the exit status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943249/python-argparse-and-controlling-overriding-the-exit-status-code#5943389) or [python argparse - add action to subparser with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594491/python-argparse-add-action-to-subparser-with-no-arguments) might help.

In the first it shows how you can override the quit and in the second how can you add subcommands or quitactions.

Comment: Tes What i need is to be able to give command without quit the program. Like when you Click a button to do an action then Click another to do another action but without closing the program