# How do I check for a particular subparser?

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

How do I check for a particular subparser?

```
import argparse
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    submainadder = mainparser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')
    parser_ut = submainadder.add_parser('unittest')
    stuff = mainparser.parse_args()
    # if 'unittest' was selected:
    #     do_things()
```

Comment: Maybe you find useful this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073688/how-to-use-argparse-subparsers-correctly

Comment: Have you tried giving `add_subparsers` a `dest='cmdname'` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
import argparse

def do_things(args):
    print args
    # Do your stuff

mainparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
submainadder = mainparser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')
parser_ut = submainadder.add_parser('unittest')
parser_ut.set_defaults(func=do_things)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stuff = mainparser.parse_args()
    stuff.func(stuff)
```

More explanations can be found here:

[python argparse - add action to subparser with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594491/python-argparse-add-action-to-subparser-with-no-arguments)

Comment: `dest='subcommand'` you may also add the `dest` keyword to `add_subparser` and highlight its existence and particular usefulness here